# Rest Assured: Fail to deserialize json response to its POJO

Tags: rest, automation, automated-tests, rest-assured

I have the following returned JSON from Azure login REST call:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "ext_expires_in": "3600",
    "expires_on": "1560857196",
    "not_before": "1560853296",
    "resource": "https://management.azure.com",
    "access_token": "d9f9s..." //I cut the value significantly here...
}
```

The POJO I built for it is as follows:

```
public class AzureLoginResponse {

    private String tokenType;
    private String expiresIn;
    private String extExpiresIn;
    private String expiresOn;
    private String notBefore;
    private String resource;
    private String accessToken; 

    //setters\getters

}
```

When I am doing this:

```
   @Given("^Azure Login Request Executed$")
    public void azureLoginExecuted() {

        RestAssured.baseURI = BASE_URI;

        Response response =
        given()  //Add x-www-form-urlencoded body params:
            .formParam(GRANT_TYPE_KEY, GRANT_TYPE_VALUE)
            .formParam(AUTO_TEAM_CLIENT_ID_KEY, AUTO_TEAM_CLIENT_ID_VALUE)
            .formParam(AUTO_TEAM_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY, AUTO_TEAM_CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE)
            .formParam(RESOURCE_KEY, RESOURCE_VALUE)
        .when()
            .post(AUTO_TEAM_TENANT_ID + RESOURCE); //Send the request along with the resource

        AzureLoginResponse azureLoginResponse = response.as(AzureLoginResponse.class);

    }
```

azureLoginResponse gets the following data in it:

```
azureLoginResponse = {AzureLoginResponse@3532} 
 tokenType = null
 expiresIn = null
 extExpiresIn = null
 expiresOn = null
 notBefore = null
 resource = "https://management.azure.com"
 accessToken = null
```

so, only 'resource' property is getting populated, whereas tests like

```
assertThat(expires_in_val, greaterThan(min_expected_expires_in_val));
```

or

```
response.then().body("resource", equalTo(expected_resource));
```

pass with no troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POJO keys doesn't match with the keys coming in response, hence the null value. As you can see the keys coming in response is snake_case and the one used in your POJO is camelCase.